# GC overhead limit exceeded while multiple threads trying to fetch data from database

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

i have a table that has nearly 7 million data in it and will get even bigger in the future! i try to fetch data using multiple threads. my approach is to fetch data in a paging manner and give each page to a thread. in other word get data within 14 pages. each has 500,000 data. hence creating 14 threads.

like this:

```
public Response determineOwnership(){
        ZonedDateTime from = ZonedDateTime.now();
        int NUM_OF_THREADS = 14;
        try {
            List<Future<List<String[]>>> futures = new ArrayList<>(0);
            ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor)               
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS);
            for (int i = 500000; i <= 7000000; i = i + 500000) {
                String query = "SELECT * from (SELECT u.usr_mobile,u.national_code,rownum r from usr_mobile_verification u) where r > " + (i - 500000) + " and r <= " + i;
                JdbcMTSample callable = new JdbcMTSample(query);
                Future<List<String[]>> result = executor.submit(callable);
                futures.add(result);
            }
            executor.shutdown();
//these are the next steps to be done. get the futures and merge them into a big list and ... .it blows before arriving here
            for (Future f : futures) {
                try {
                    f.get();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    return ResponseHelper.serverError();
                }
            }
            ZonedDateTime to = ZonedDateTime.now();
            return ResponseHelper.ok("took " + Duration.between(from, to).toMinutes() + " Minutes");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseHelper.serverError();
        }
}
```

`JdbcMTSample` class:

```
public class JdbcMTSample implements Runnable {
    
    int m_myId;
    private String query;
    static int c_nextId = 1;
    static Connection s_conn = null;

    synchronized static int getNextId() {
        return c_nextId++;
    }


    public JdbcMTSample(String query) {
        super();
        this.query=query;
        // Assign an ID to the thread
        m_myId = getNextId();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("...","...", "...");
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
          query="update usr_mobile_verification m set m.is_owner=? where m.national_code=?";
            while (rs.next()) {
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                stmt.setString(2,rs.getString("NATIONAL_CODE"));
                if (isContactInfoValid(rs.getString("USR_MOBILE"),rs.getString("NATIONAL_CODE")))
                    stmt.setString(1, "1");
                else
                    stmt.setString(1, "0");
                stmt.executeQuery();
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Thread " + m_myId + " is finished. ");
           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Thread " + m_myId + " got Exception: " + e);
           
        }
    }
}
```

note that if i don't return the list and just return void instead all threads will do their work and everything will be ok. but i need to return the list at the end cos i will do some operations on it in the next level. how should i return the list at the end and merge them into a final list?

P.S: i have increased heap size by `-Xms1g -Xmx2g`. also i can't just query the database and get the result list in the normal way cos it takes too much time and will result in out of memory.

```
            -------------------UPDATE-----------------------
```

to get rid of out of memory exception i decided not to store anything in any variable. because at the end i need to update a column in the table and no need to return anything. thus i edited `JdbcMTSample` class. but again it takes too much time. even increasing the number of threads would have worse effect. what should i do for this?

Comment: Have you tried to simply disable disable the limitation with -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Read `NATIONAL_CODE` and `USR_MOBILE` into Java heap memory for all 7 mln database records? Having more threads won't help you here, the heap memory is still the same even if you have more threads.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki this is my question. what should i do then? i used threads to speed up fetching operation.

Comment: Start by explaining what is your actuall problem e.g. you need to sum values of two columns for 7 mln records. It feels like you have [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), usually you can process all these 7 mln records directly in the database.

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli yes but it didn't help

Comment: @KarolDowbecki fetch all data in the table then loop thru each one and give mobile phone and national code as inputs to a remote rest service and based on that update a column in that table. this is the job

Comment: You’ve chosen one of the most inefficient ways to represent the row data in your memory, an array of strings. Compared to a dedicated object holding a `long` and an `int`, you’re easily consuming more than ten times the needed memory. Still, that’d roughly consume 1GB of memory and still fit into your heap memory. But there’s the unknown and uncontrollable overhead within the JDBC driver itself. Go with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66644337/2711488) and don’t read everything into memory. And use *less* threads when the I/O bandwidth is the actual bottleneck. And try a newer JDK.

Answer (score 1):

"GC overhead limit exceeded" is a variant of `OutOfMemoryError` caused by garbage collector not finding sufficient memory to free within a garbage collection cycle. You can take a look at [this Plumbr article](https://plumbr.io/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) to see how to debug the problem further and understand which objects are taking up memory.

The situation can be fixed in two ways:

1. Improve your algorithm logic to allocate less objects.
2. Keep increasing the JVM heap (`-Xmx`) until there is enough memory for your current algorithm logic.

Comment: don't think increasing ```-Xmx``` would help. what is the maximum amount for that?

Comment: @reza - Increasing `-Xmx` *could* help ... if you have enough RAM to make the heap large enough.  But it is a wasteful solution if option 1 is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the JVM is running out of memory, i.e. using more memory than it has.

> fetch all data in the table then loop thru each one and give mobile phone and national code as inputs to a remote rest service and based on that update a column in that table. this is the job

Fortunately, this task doesn't require the entire table to be in memory at the same time. Rather than loading all rows, then do all API requests, and then write everything back into the db, you can load some rows, do some requests, and write that back into the db, and repeat this until you are done. That way, only some rows need to be in memory at the same time, rather than all rows.

This is typically accomplished with the help of a framework such as Spring Batch. This also provides additional features you might want, such as the ability to resume an update that has been interrupted.

Comment: Please user Spring batch as @meriton mentioned above . I have attached example below to process huge volume

Comment: @Rakesh i can't use spring libraries as i am using jakarta ee and can't use any other thing. its a huge project

Comment: @reza - to avoid confusion spring batch details are deleted as its not match with your requirement.  Spring batch follows jakarta ee batch specification  and re-inventing the complete batch capability is little tricky to handle huge volume and maintainability